# project/bin after install, howto use the scripts

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to learn Python distribute package, and can't seems figure out the `/bin` part myself. The Foo package installed and I can reference to it by using `from FOO import Foo`.

For example, if I had a project named `foo`, and I have a script, called `use-foo`, after I 
put 'use-foo' inside my `foo/bin`, how I am suppose to use it?

The project source file/directory structure looks like this:

```
foo
-->FOO (source code for foo)
    -->Foo.py
-->bin (script uses Foo goes here)
    -->use-foo.py
```

I've tried `import use-foo`, `from foo import use-foo` not working, relative path?

Add setup.py:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'My Foo Project', 
    'author': 'Paul Liu',
    'url': 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email': 'My email.',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires':['nose'],
    'packages':['FOO'],
    'scripts':['bin/use-foo.py'],
    'name': 'foo'
}

setup(**config)
```

Comment: Is this the result of running your setup.py build? Or is this just your source project structure? Is this a complete python package structure or the entire distribution package?

Comment: It is my source project structure. Not sure about second question, so I just attache my setup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source directory alone is only where you will develop your code. It doesn't really reflect the final product (installed) form until you have it build by one of the available commands (or manually add the various paths to your env).

To develop, what you can do is run this: `python setup.py develop`
This will install an egg in your python site-packages that is really just a link back to your source location. Meaning that you can actively edit code, and it will reflect in your PYTHONPATH. The build process will place the package `FOO` into your PYTHONPATH, and copy everything in your scripts to the python `bin`. For instance on my machine:

> Creating
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/foo.egg-link
>   (link to .)
>   Installing use-foo.py script to
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin

Now in your `use-foo.py`, you can refer to `FOO` as the import package, as it will exist in the python path. If you choose not to use the `develop` command, you would need to manually add `foo/` to your PYTHONPATH, so that it will find the `FOO` package underneath.

**Most important here**: add a `__init__.py` file (empty) to your `FOO` package. This is required for python to recognize it as a package.

---

#### Manual environment paths

Adding paths manually to your shell environment might look like this (bash shell):

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/foo:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=/path/to/foo/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks jdi, I finally got it working. Turn out that in Windows, `Python27/Scripts` is not in system `PATH`. Other than that, `python setup.py install` should working as well. But it is really nice to know `python setup.py develop` tip for development. Sorry about `__init__.py` file, I actually have it, but been lazy, didn't mention in my post.